# Reverse an onClick event

Tags: onclick, hide, show, reverse

I've got this code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#gallery').click(function(){
        $('.overlay').fadeIn(500);
        $('#infographic').delay(800).fadeIn(200);
    });
});
```

Now when I click `$('#gallery')` again, I want the above to reverse.

Anyone??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(function(){
    $('#gallery').click(function(){
        $('.overlay').toggle(500);
        $('#infographic').delay(800).toggle(200);
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Ok this seems to work, however I did need to add a button. That doesn't matter though. But now he doesn't fade in, can I add that somewhere?

Comment: try setting `$('.overlay').toggle("slow");` and `$('#infographic').delay(800).toggle("slow")`. You can use "fast", if you want it faster.

Comment: hmm doesn't seem to work... it just comes in form the top left corner

Comment: Fixed it with 'fadeToggle', didn't know you could do that. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Since your fade-in has the infographic starting 300ms after the overlay finishes, I've reversed the steps and modified the delay so that the overlay will fade out 300ms after the infographic does. The following code will exactly reverse your fade-in.

```
$(function(){
    $('#gallery').click(function(){
        // Check the current state - are things visible? If yes, fade out
        if ($('#inforgraphic').is(':visible')) {
            $('#infographic').fadeOut(200);
            $('.overlay').delay(500).fadeOut(500);
        // If not visible, fade in
        } else {
            $('.overlay').fadeIn(500);
            $('#infographic').delay(800).fadeIn(200);
        }
    });
});
```